# What is the linq to entity query for SQL IN statement

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What is the linq to entity query for the below SQL statement

```
Select * from table where id in (‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, …..So on Millions)
```

Comment: Are you using EFv1 (.NET 3.5) or later?

Answer (score 0):

put  (‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, …..So on Millions) in a list

then below is the LINQ to Entity query ->

```
from t in tables where list.contains(t.id) select t
```

Comment: I tried your solution but getting this error 'base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}'

Comment: Can you please send me the exact code you have written for this so that I can tell you the exact solution?